# Gap in Delphi TFlowLayout

Tags: delphi, layout

> Hello, I have different TFlowLayouts, and with the same horizontal and
> vertical gap, it works except in a group. The second line doesn't
> respect the gaps. Do you have any idea?

[image]

Comment: Please provide means to replicate the problem

Comment: Likely ChangesRules is set for the break and it has new values that are used for the gaps.

Comment: E.g. add your `.fmx` file as text to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TFlowLayoutBreak has a ChangesRules property.

> If ChangesRules is True, the child controls added after the
> TFlowLayoutBreak are positioned following the rules specified through
> the TFlowLayoutBreak properties, until all controls are displayed or
> another TFlowLayoutBreak if found.

So likely you have this property set to true and have gap values set for the break different from those for the flowlayout itself.

Comment: Thanks you it works; So simple when you know; I have 6 TFlowLayoutBreak and it was the only one whith ChangesRules set ;)